# Why does elasticsearch terms bucket size effects the doc_count of inner reverse_nested aggregations?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I've been trying to track down missing doc counts from a reverse nested aggregation.

My query

```
"aggs": {
    "mainGrouping": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "parent.child"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "uniqueCount": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "parent.child.id"
          }
        },
        "groupBy": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "parent.child.id",
            "size": 20,  <- If I change this, my doc count for noOfParents changes
            "order": [
              {
                "noOfParents": "desc"
              }
            ]
          },
          "aggs": {
            "noOfParents": {
              "reverse_nested": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

So I was running it at `size:20`.  I had one bucket that returned noOfParents of 7 when I know there should be 9 matches.  I noticed by accident if I change the size of the terms aggregation to 50 the noOfParents was correctly showing 9 for this bucket.

Why would the size of the terms aggregation affect the doc_count of a reverse aggregation? Is this expected behaviour or a bug?  I'm using elasticsearch 5.6.

Answer (score 1):

What you are observing is most likely normal behavior of [`terms`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) aggregation, because **document counts are approximate**. This is not related neither to `reverse_nested`, neither to `nested` aggregations.

In short, since the data is spread over the shards, Elasticsearch makes its best guess first locally on each shard and then combines the result across the shards. For a better, more detailed explanation please check out [this section of the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts).

To make sure this is actually the case you may add a `top_hits` aggregation with `explain` enabled:

```
      "aggs": {
        "noOfParents": {
          "reverse_nested": {},
          "aggs": {
            "top hits": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 10,
                "explain": true
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

This will give you the list of the matched parent documents with their shard ids. Something like this:

```
  "aggregations": {
    "mainGrouping": {
      ...
      "groupBy": {
        ...
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "1",
            "doc_count": 5,
            "noOfParents": {
              "doc_count": 5,
              "top hits": {
                "hits": {
                  "total": 5,
                  "max_score": 1,
                  "hits": [
                    {
                      "_shard": "[my-index-2018-12][0]", <-- this is the shard
                      "_node": "7JNqOhTtROqzQR9QBUENcg",
                      "_index": "my-index-2018-12",
                      "_type": "doc",
                      "_id": "AWdpyZ4Y3HZjlM-Ibd7O",
                      "_score": 1,
                      "_source": {
                        "parent": "A",
                        "child": {
                          "id": "1"
                        }
                      },
                      "_explanation": ...
                    },
```

Another way to prove that this is the source of the problem is to isolate the query within one shard. To do so it is enough to add [routing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/mapping-routing-field.html) to the search request: `?routing=0`

This will make your `terms` buckets counts stable within one shard. Then compare the `noOfParents` with the expected amount of parents (again, within the same shard).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to the reply. It was dropping a result from one shard. Looks like raising the size is my only option. I will look at using Composite when we move to version 6.